# how create hibernate criteria query for given sql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, nhibernate, hibernate-criteria

How can I write  hibernate criteria query for given sql query?

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
AND (City='Berlin' OR City='Munchen');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customers.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Country", "Germany"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
                             Restrictions.eq("City", "Berlin"),
                             Restrictions.eq("City", "Munchen")));
```

### See Also

- [Hibernate docs Chapter 15. Criteria Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)